# Weird including problems with AFNetwork?

Tags: iphone, include, afnetworking

I've just downloaded AFNetworking to try and mess with it, but i'm having weird errors on including it in my project.

I've just created an empty test project and dropped both AFNetworking and JSONKit in, and immediately i got the error "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h' file not found" .

It happens in this row, but changing it to a regular import works for some reason. I could change all of them but I'm trying to understand why this is happening to begin with. I'm sure its some stupid configuration i didn't notice.

```cpp
#import <AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h> // Throws error
#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"  // Works
```

Thanks ! :)
Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '#import ' syntax is for framework import.

If you just drag&drop the source in your project you've to use '#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"'

If you want use a .framework this tutorial can help you: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer :)

Answer (score 3):

`<AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h>` works if you add AFNetworking as a framework. If you added the files you have to replace the imports with just `"AFURLConnectionOperation.h"`.